# How to show data from database?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I switched computer and I lost some of my code and I am having trouble displaying the data from my database.

T

Answer (score 1):

Use this function instead of mysql_fetch_array: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php

And then you will get an array with elements named after mysql table fields.
`$row['name'], $row['last_name'], $row['email']` will be there.

Comment: Please check my updated question code, the data still isn't showing. What else can i do?

Comment: I dont see any code in question now. You can for example do var_dump($row); before echo's and see for yourself what is in array. Maybe you've got wrong field names.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your database table name is "information" and  fields are name,roll and age.

Now you want to show data in a php page from table "information".

Code :

```
$info="select * from information";
$res=mysql_query($info); 
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
  {
    echo $row['name'];
    echo $row['roll'];
    echo $row['age'];
  }
```

Comment: I did this but now i get an error message saying:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO, expecting ',' or ';' in /websites/123reg/LinuxPackage22/we/ez/y_/weezy.co.uk/public_html/newresults.php on line 100

Comment: the 100th line is:

echo $row['lastname']

Comment: You'll have to add `;` after each and every line. I edited this answer  to include them.

Comment: Still nothing? I edited my question php code to what it is now please check it! Thanks!